# Error when executing sudo rm commands in shell script (osascript) on MacOS

Tags: macos, shell

I want to learn about scripting in mac, this is my first script based on what I found on the web, i'm just trying to delete some files (MySQL) after show some dialogs, the dialogs works fine, but when I put the `sudo rm lines` it doesn't work, it says `Syntax Error`, this is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript <<EOT
 app "System Events"
set answer to the button returned of (display dialog "You want to delete MySQL?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button 2)
if (answer = "No") then
display dialog "Canceled" buttons {"ok"}
else
if (answer = "Yes")then
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysql.plist
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.st.plist
set answer to the button returned of (display dialog "MySQL deleted, restart necesary.\nrestart now?" buttons {"Yes","Restart Later"}default button 2)
end if
end if
return  -- Suppress result
end
EOT
```

EDIT: 
I try like @that other guy says like this:

```
`do shell script "sudo rm /usr/local/mysql && 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql && 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql* && 
sudo rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist && 
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM && 
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My* && 
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.* && 
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL* && 
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql* && 
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysql.plist && 
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.st.plist"`
```

But if one command fail the execution just stop.

Comment: The Mac Automation Scripting Guide [suggests using `do shell script`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/CallCommandLineUtilities.html) to embed shell commands in an AppleScript, e.g. `do shell script "ls /Applications/"`

Comment: Why are you trying to use `sudo` *after* launching `osascript`, rather than before?

Comment: That is to say, `sudo osascript` will run the whole thing as root, so you don't need to use `sudo` anywhere after that point.

Comment: You can use `;` instead of `&&` to continue regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @thatotherguy, @CharlesDuffy and @zneak, here is the script working perfectly:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo osascript <<EOT
 app "System Events"
set answer to the button returned of (display dialog "You want to delete MySQL?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button 2)
if (answer = "No") then
display dialog "Canceled" buttons {"ok"}
else
if (answer = "Yes")then
do shell script "sudo rm /usr/local/mysql;
rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql;
rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*;
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist;
rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM;
rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*;
rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*;
rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*;
rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*;
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysql.plist;
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.st.plist;"

set answer2 to the button returned of (display dialog "MySQL deleted, restart necesary.\nrestart now?" buttons {"Yes","Restart Later"}default button 2)
if (answer2 = "Yes")then
tell app "System Events" to restart

end if
end if
return  -- Suppress result
end
EOT
```